# How to determine cell value based on comparing other cells to find the fastest and slowest durations?

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I have a set of columns in a Google Sheet which are calculating the average duration between two times. I would like to calculate a score in the cells marked with an `X` based on the calculated averages. The goal being to award 75 for the fastest, 50 for second and 25 for third. In the example below that would mean that Yellow’s score cell would be 75, Green’s would be 50 and Blue’s would be 25.

| Run | Fastest Time | Slowest Time | Average | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Green | 10:02:01 | 17:22:11 | 13:42:06 | X |
| Blue | 10:07:08 | 18:22:12 | 14:14:40 | X |
| Yellow | 10:11:09 | 16:07:11 | 13:09:10 | X |

I am assuming that some sort of `VLOOKUP` or `IF` function should be used but given the comparison between the averages I’m not sure how to put the function together. How do I calculate a cell value based on the comparison of other cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using RANK with IF function to assign the points for top 3. See the example. The below formula is used on E2 cell as in my example.  Adjust it based on your needs. D$2:D$4 is the range of cells that you want to compare the results.

`=IF(RANK(D2,D$2:D$4,1)=1,75,IF(RANK(D2,D$2:D$4,1)=2,50,IF(RANK(D2,D$2:D$4,1)=3,25,"Not on top 3")))`

It will return 75 for the fastest average time, 50 for the second, 25 for third and "Not on top 3" for the rest.

With this formula, if there are 2 exact times, they will get the same points (if fastest time is shared by 2 teams, they will get both 75 points, then the next one will get 25 points. there will be no 50 points awarded)

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want to get the 3 fastest numbers and associate scores with them.

Fastest

```
=IF(SMALL($A$1:$A$8;3 )=A1;"Third";
    IF(SMALL($A$1:$A$8;2)=A1;"Second";
        IF(SMALL($A$1:$A$8;1)=A1;"First";"No points for you")))
```

Slowest

```
=IF(LARGE($A$1:$A$8;3 )=A1;"At least beat 2";
    IF(LARGE($A$1:$A$8;2)=A1;"Not the slowest";
        IF(LARGE($A$1:$A$8;1)=A1;"Slowest";"No points for you")))
```

Now you need to use this for the slowest, although you will need another column. You can hide both and on a third one reflect the content of those columns with an if like this

```
=IF(B1="No points 4 you";C1;IF(C1="No points 4 you";B1;B1))
```

Here is a picture of my setup so you can edit according to yours

[image]

Bye